# How to make a list of lists of n numbers including x-z numbers

Tags: java, list, for-loop, dart

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, because I couldn't come up with how to explain the question shortly, so if it had been, please point me in the right direction.

So I want to know how to create a function in Java to create a list of lists. In these lists, I want all possibilities of the numbers 0-5, but only 4 numbers in each list. I've done this in a simple way, where I can hardcode the 4 in, but I don't want to hardcode that number in.

Here is what I have, written in Dart.

```dart
void generateLists() {
  // possibles holds all the possible options. (1296 options in this case)
  List<List<int>> possibles = new List();
  int size = 4; // This should be the size of each list. This is what I'm asking about.
  int maxNum = 6; // The numbers should go from 0 - maxNum.


  // A terrible amount of for loops within each other to generate these lists.
  for(int i=0; i<maxNum; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<maxNum; j++) {
      for(int k=0; k<maxNum; k++) {
        for(int l=0; l<maxNum; l++) {
          // Create each list and add it to the possibles.
          List<int> list = new List();
          list.add(i);
          list.add(j);
          list.add(k);
          list.add(l);
          possibles.add(list);
        }
      } 
    }

  }

  // Print all the numbers to show it works.
  for(List<int> l in possibles) {
    print(l);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am writing this application in Dart, but if anyone has an example in Java or something similar, that would be fine too. Thanks again.

Comment: I think I am looking at a possible permutations problem. Are you? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/permutations-of-a-list-of-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [Iterable.expand](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-core.Iterable@id_expand) :

```dart
main() {
  int size = 4;
  int maxNum = 6;

  // create a list of nums [0,1,2,3]
  final nums = new List.generate(maxNum, (i) => i);

  // init result with a list of nums [[0],[1],[2],[3]]
  Iterable<List> result = nums.map((i) => [i]);
  for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
    // every step adds a new element to the result
    // [[0],[1],...] becomes [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1],...]
    result = result.expand((e) => nums.map((n) => e.toList()..add(n)));
  }
  result.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: This is really fast too. About 1/5 of the time my solution takes.

Comment: I was a little surprised by the speed too. I initially thought your solution was more fast. BTW `result` is lazy and you have to call `length` or `toList()` to get a real time.

Comment: Yeah, I fell in that trap. If you create a List with `toList()` it takes about double time, if you just iterate over it its about 1.5x. `map` and `expand` must be implemented in the VM, it's not possible to step in with the debugger. I always like your `expand`/`map` solutions! I hope I get more fluent with them too.

Comment: A big advantage (beside the elegance) of your solution is the lazy evaluation. My solution throws 'out of memory' beginning with `size = 9;`. I haven't tried with `toList()` (will very probably throw too) but just iterating over the list works just fine for a size of 9.

Answer (score 1):

This code just counts and when the least significant number gets to high it increases the next more significant number that is lower than maxNum.

The outer loop is iterated for each result.
The inner loop is entered after each maxNum iterations and runs minimum 1 times to maximum size -1  times.

```
void main() {
  // possibles holds all the possible options. (1296 options in this case)
  List<List<int>> possibles = new List();
  int size = 4; // This should be the size of each list. This is what I'm asking about.
  int maxNum = 6; // The numbers should go from 0 - maxNum.


  List<int> cur = new List<int>(size);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cur[i] = 0;

  while(cur[0] < maxNum) {
    possibles.add(new List.from(cur));

    int pos = size-1;
    cur[pos]++;
    bool overflow = cur[pos] >= maxNum;
    while(overflow && size > 0 && pos > 0) {
      cur[pos] = 0;
      pos--;
      cur[pos]++;
      overflow = cur[pos] >= maxNum;
    }
  }

  // Print all the numbers to show it works.
  for(List<int> l in possibles) {
    print(l);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

This code preallocates the outer list to avoid that the list must be increased repeatedly and is slightly faster.

```
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
  sw.start();

  // possibles holds all the possible options. (1296 options in this case)
  List<List<int>> possibles;
  int size = 8; // This should be the size of each list. This is what I'm asking about.
  int maxNum = 6; // The numbers should go from 0 - maxNum.

  int resultCount = pow(maxNum, size);
  possibles = new List(resultCount);

  List<int> cur = new List<int>(size);
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) cur[i] = 0;

  int cnt = 0;

  while(cur[0] < maxNum) {
    possibles[cnt] = new List.from(cur);
    cnt++;

    int pos = size-1;
    cur[pos]++;
    bool overrun = cur[pos] >= maxNum;
    while(overrun && size > 0 && pos > 0) {
      cur[pos] = 0;
      pos--;
      cur[pos]++;
      overrun = cur[pos] >= maxNum;
    }
  }

  sw.stop();
  print('elapsed: ${sw.elapsed}');

  // Print all the numbers to show it works.
  for(List<int> l in possibles) {
    print(l);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this solution the most. Thanks for the quick replies.

Answer (score 1):

You're really just counting from 0 ... maxNum ^ size in a base of maxNum. An easy way to formulate this would be to generate a list of ints, then map the ints to lists of digits in the new base.

Here I cheat a little use int.toRadixString() and quiver.strings.padLeft, but it's pretty readable:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;
import 'package:quiver/strings.dart' show padLeft;

main() {
  int digits = 4;
  int base = 6;
  var result = new Iterable.generate(pow(base, digits),
      (i) => padLeft(i.toRadixString(base), digits, '0').split('').map(int.parse));
  result.forEach(print);
}
```

And this is a way to do it without going to Strings and back:

```dart
import 'dart:math' show pow;

List<int> splitDigits(int i, int base, int width) {
  var digits = new List<int>.filled(width, 0);
  int digit = 0;
  while (i != 0) {
    digits[width - ++digit] = i % base;
    i = i ~/ base;
  }
  return digits;
}

main() {
  int digits = 4;
  int base = 6;
  var result = new Iterable.generate(pow(base, digits),
      (i) => splitDigits(i, base, digits));
  result.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution is about as fast as the one from @AlexandreArdhuin and the second about as fast as mine, but still lazy (as long as you only iterate over the result and don't call `result.toList()`). My first idea was like your first solution but I didn't think of `toRadixString` and I tried to avoid the `toString`/`split` operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a 2 dimensional int array.

```
int[][] myArray = new int[size][];
```

and then you'd only have to loop twice:

```
for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
   for(int j=0 j<maxNum; j++){
      myArray[i][j] = numberYouWantToAdd;
   }
}
```

then you can just access the numbers via:

```
myArray[whichList][whichItemOfThatList]
```

Comment: This would create size amount of identical arrays though. I need permutations.

Answer (score 0):

**Recursion**.

```dart
class Permutation<T> {

    Permutation(List<T> pool, int maxElements) {
        this._permutations = [];
        this._permutate([], pool, maxElements);
    }

    List<List<T>> get result => this._permutations;
    List<List<T>> _permutations;

    void _permutate(List<T> permutation, List<T> pool, int maxElements) {
        int n = pool.length;
        if(n > 0 && permutation.length < maxElements) {
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
                List<T> newPermutation = new List.from(permutation);
                newPermutation.add(pool[i]);
                List<T> newPool = new List.from(pool);
                newPool.removeAt(i);
                this._permutate(newPermutation, newPool, maxElements);
            }
        } else {
            this._permutations.add(permutation);
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    List<int> pool = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
    print(new Permutation<int>(pool, 4).result);
}
```

And a quick [google search](https://www.google.de/#q=java+create+permutations) delivers many code examples for Java.

Comment: This one didn't seem to work completely. I believe it's missing duplicates, which I need for my problem. Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

The same program in Dart can be written as following in Java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Demonstration
{
  public Demonstration()
  {
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> lists = getListOfList();

    printList(lists);
  }

  // Here's the function implementation you want.
  private ArrayList<List<Integer>> getListOfList()
  {
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

    final int maxSize = 6;

    // The 4 nested loops still take constant time as the value of `maxSize` is constant.
    // I would have created a permutation based solution only if maxSize varied.
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < maxSize; ++k)
        {
          for (int w = 0; w < maxSize; ++w)
          {
            list.add(Arrays.asList(i, j, k, w));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  private void printList(ArrayList<List<Integer>> lists)
  {
    lists.forEach(System.out::println); // JDK 8 standard
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Demonstration();
  }
}
```

One can even write the program using a 2D array of ints. Here's how to do that:

```
public class Demonstration
{
  public Demonstration2()
  {
    int[][] lists = getListOfList();

    printList(lists);
  }

  private int[][] getListOfList()
  {
    final int maxSize = 6;

    int[][] list = new int[maxSize * maxSize * maxSize * maxSize][];
    int rowIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; ++i)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < maxSize; ++j)
      {
        for (int k = 0; k < maxSize; ++k)
        {
          for (int w = 0; w < maxSize; ++w)
          {
            list[rowIndex++] = new int[]{i, j, k, w};
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return list;
  }

  private void printList(int[][] lists)
  {
    for (int[] list : lists)
    {
      for (int item : list)
      {
        System.out.print(item + " ");
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Demonstration();
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't asking how to write exactly what I had in Java. I was asking for a better way to do it, without all the for loops. Thanks though.